# Django Handle big files ( imageblob )

Tags: python, django, blob, sorl-thumbnail

I am writing a small gallery app and after extensive testing i submitted a 3mb image.

Basically the gallery app relies on another app that creates an UploadedFile instance for every image, however i see that for this specific image it has created 4 instances ( rows in db ) that belong to the same 3mb image, each image has "blob" at the end of its name.

My question is, how can i handle an image as big as this and be able to refer to the whole image ? in a html tag or django templatetag like sorl-thumbnail's ?

Im using python 2.7.2, Django 1.3.1 and MySQL 5.1

Comment: Have you considered perhaps not storing the images in the DB, but instead storing them as files on disk and simply storing the filenames in the DB?

Comment: I am using django's file field, and as far as i know the images are being stored as files in disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue was the Jquery plugin that i was using to upload multiple files. The plugin was the one who split the file into chunks which were then sent individually as POST requests, and django didn't know that blob1, blob2, blob3, blob4 where the same file in chunks.